# MySQL different query results on local versus remote server

Tags: mysql, environment-variables

I made a copy of a MySQL database to a remote server through an SQL query.

Remote server:

```
Variable_name               Value
protocol_version            10
slave_type_conversions      
version                     10.0.11-MariaDB
version_comment             MariaDB Server
version_compile_machine     x86_64
version_compile_os          Linux
version_malloc_library      system
```

Local server:

```
Variable_name               Value   
innodb_version              5.6.21  
protocol_version            10  
slave_type_conversions      
version                     5.6.21  
version_comment             MySQL Community Server (GPL)    
version_compile_machine     x86 
version_compile_os          Win32
```

When I run following query this produces a different result on either server.

```
select K, S, rn as R, G, V, T, Naam, Club, R1, R2, R3, R4, R5, R6, Totaal
from (
    select K, S, G, V, T, Naam, Club, R1, R2, R3, R4, R5, R6, R1+R2+R3+R4+R5+R6 as Totaal,
        @rn := case when @prev = S
                    then @rn + 1
                    else 1
                end as rn,
        @prev := S
    from (
        select K, substr(K,1,1) as S, G, V, T, L.Naam, C.naam as Club, coalesce(R1,0) R1, coalesce(R2,0) R2, coalesce(R3,0) R3, coalesce(R4,0) R4, coalesce(R5,0) R5, coalesce(R6,0) R6 
        from (
            select clubid, naam from club) as C
                join (select clubid, bondsnummer, if(mv="M", "Dhr.", "Mw.") as G, voorletters as V, tussenvoegsel as T, achternaam as Naam from lid where mv="M") as L on C.clubid=L.clubid
                join (select bondsnummer, klasse as K, compdnid from deelnemer) as D on L.bondsnummer=D.bondsnummer
                left join (select compdnid, rondeid, sum(score) as R1 from score where rondeid=1 group by compdnid,rondeid) as R1 on D.compdnid=R1.compdnid
                left join (select compdnid, sum(score) as R2 from score where rondeid=2 group by compdnid,rondeid) as R2 on R1.compdnid=R2.compdnid
                left join (select compdnid, sum(score) as R3 from score where rondeid=3 group by compdnid,rondeid) as R3 on R2.compdnid=R3.compdnid
                left join (select compdnid, sum(score) as R4 from score where rondeid=4 group by compdnid,rondeid) as R4 on R3.compdnid=R4.compdnid
                left join (select compdnid, sum(score) as R5 from score where rondeid=5 group by compdnid,rondeid) as R5 on R4.compdnid=R5.compdnid
                left join (select compdnid, sum(score) as R6 from score where rondeid=6 group by compdnid,rondeid) as R6 on R5.compdnid=R6.compdnid
    ) as S, (select @prev := 0, @rn := 0) as vars
    order by S, Totaal desc 
) as X
where Totaal > 0
limit 0,500
```

Result on local server, with correct numbering of @rn as R:

[image]

And on remote server numering in column R goes wrong:

[image]

(Note that on the local server the records cannot be edited, deleted, ... as opposed to remote. See first few columns 'wijzigen, verwijderen, ...' that only appear remote. Not that I need to do so, I just wonder what the difference comes from.)

Explain? How to solve or look for what causes this?

Comment: You are using `limit` without an `order by` (in the outer query).  The ordering of result sets is not guaranteed by an `order by` on a subquery, especially when using a parallel database such as MariaDB.  Put an `order by` in the outer query if you want consistent results.

Comment: I tried that now. The result is that I get the same incorrect pattern on BOTH servers as when running the (still unchanged) query on the remote server. So this is definitely the issue but your suggestion doesn't seem to be the exact or complete solution? Or should the queries be different for both servers?

Answer (score 0):

Why use a subquery at all?  Just put all the logic in one query:

```
select K, S, G, V, T, Naam, Club, R1, R2, R3, R4, R5, R6,
       (R1+R2+R3+R4+R5+R6) as Totaal,
    @rn := case when @prev = S
                then @rn + 1
                else 1
            end as rn,
    @prev := S
from (
    select K, substr(K,1,1) as S, G, V, T, L.Naam, C.naam as Club, coalesce(R1,0) R1, coalesce(R2,0) R2, coalesce(R3,0) R3, coalesce(R4,0) R4, coalesce(R5,0) R5, coalesce(R6,0) R6 
    from (
        select clubid, naam from club) as C
            join (select clubid, bondsnummer, if(mv="M", "Dhr.", "Mw.") as G, voorletters as V, tussenvoegsel as T, achternaam as Naam from lid where mv="M") as L on C.clubid=L.clubid
            join (select bondsnummer, klasse as K, compdnid from deelnemer) as D on L.bondsnummer=D.bondsnummer
            left join (select compdnid, rondeid, sum(score) as R1 from score where rondeid=1 group by compdnid,rondeid) as R1 on D.compdnid=R1.compdnid
            left join (select compdnid, sum(score) as R2 from score where rondeid=2 group by compdnid,rondeid) as R2 on R1.compdnid=R2.compdnid
            left join (select compdnid, sum(score) as R3 from score where rondeid=3 group by compdnid,rondeid) as R3 on R2.compdnid=R3.compdnid
            left join (select compdnid, sum(score) as R4 from score where rondeid=4 group by compdnid,rondeid) as R4 on R3.compdnid=R4.compdnid
            left join (select compdnid, sum(score) as R5 from score where rondeid=5 group by compdnid,rondeid) as R5 on R4.compdnid=R5.compdnid
            left join (select compdnid, sum(score) as R6 from score where rondeid=6 group by compdnid,rondeid) as R6 on R5.compdnid=R6.compdnid
) as S, (select @prev := 0, @rn := 0) as vars
where (R1+R2+R3+R4+R5+R6) > 0
order by S, Totaal desc 
limit 0, 500;
```

EDIT:

Your problem may not actually be the `limit` and `order by`.  It might be the variables.  MySQL does *not* guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in the `select` clause, so `prev` might be set before it is used.  You can fix this by combining the variable operations into a single expression:

```
    (@rn := if(@prev = S, @rn + 1,
               if(@prev := S, 1, 1)
              )
    ) as rn
```

This may actually fix your problem.  By the way, for SQL code, I usually prefer `case` over `if()` for conditional expressions, because `case` is standard.  However, the use of variables is highly specific to MySQL and `if()` is easier to type.

Comment: Well that is actually just to prevent @prev from showing up in the final queryresult. I might leave it in if this is the only solution. Other ways to achieve that?

Comment: @user1837293  . . . See my edit.  The variable assignment might actually be the root of your problem.

Comment: I tried that now. However it doesn't make a change: result on local server is fine, on remote server wrong as before.

Comment: I experimented a bit and found that if I use straight_join on the local server it produces the same (erronous) result as is produced (with or without straight join) on the remote server. So is there a way to force a join order in the way that is apparently default on this local server?